# How to use template literal in Firebase Cloud Function condition

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is it possible to use template literal in message condition of Firebase Cloud Function?

I tried the following but it is not working.

```
topic1 = `${myObject.id}`
topic2 = `${myObject.name}`
var condition = "topic1 in topics || topic2 in topics";

var message = {
  notification: {
    title: 'My object',
    body: 'My object.'
  },
  condition: condition
};

admin.messaging().send(message);
```

I changed to this but it is still not working:

```
      topic = "_full";
      topic1 = `${myObj.field1}` + topic;
      topic2 = (`${myObj.field2.field1}_${myObj.field2.field2}` + topic)
        .toString()
        .toLowerCase()
        .split(" ")
        .join("_");
      topic3 = `${myObj.field3.field1}` + topic;
      topic4 = `${myObj.field4.field1}` + topic;

      condition = `${topic1} in topics || ${topic2} in topics || ${topic3} in topics || ${topic4} in topics`;
```

I get "Error: Invalid condition expression provided."

Comment: What's wrong with what you have now?  Please edit the question to be clear about what isn't working the way you expect.

Comment: I tried this and it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget to add single quotes around topics:

```
var condition = `'${topic1}' in topics || '${topic2}' in topics`;
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you have `"topic1 in topics || topic2 in topics"` it is a normal string, and variables in it are not expanded. Also `topic1` is not a variable, that'd be `${topic1}`.

You can do either:

```
var condition = `${myObject.id} in topics || ${myObject.name} in topics`;
```

Or:

```
topic1 = `${myObject.id}`
topic2 = `${myObject.name}`
var condition = `${topic1} in topics || ${topic2} in topics`;
```

Comment: Your new code is a quite a bit more (complex) than what I have in my answer, and what you originally had. I recommend troubleshooting the string manipulation in the JavaScript console of your browser, as it has nothing to do with FCM or Cloud Functions.

Comment: I checked the condition with an editor and it looks fine.